# Prevent users storing files on dekstop

Tags: windows, store, desktop

Is there any way to prevent users saving / storing files (except shortcuts) on their desktop?

Messy users like download or copy huge contents and store it on their desktop, and this uses SSD place however there is a HDD for storage.

I want to be sure they place their files to the correct place (anywhere but desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Desktop destination from ssd to your storage HardDrive. What you need to do is:

1. Go to `c:\Users\YOURNAME\`
2. Right click the desktop Folder and go to `Properties`
3. go to the `Location` tab
4. There you can click `move` or write the path to where you want the
   desktop to be stored!

If you just want to disable them to store on the desktop you can change the permission on "Desktop". to do that do wollowing:

1. Go to c:\Users\YOURNAME\
2. Rightclick the Desktop folder
3. Go to `security`
4. Click `edit`
5. Choose the user you want to stop from saving on desktop
6. find where it sais "write" and turn off his permission to write to desktop.

If you don't find the spesific user on the list click `add`and write his username in the white box. Therefrom click `ok`

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74971-move-location-desktop-folder-windows-10-a.html